# Proof that a map is linear including a sum

Tags: linear-algebra

A map is linear if the following is given:

I.  $f(\lambda*\vec{x})=\lambda f(\vec{x})$
II. $f(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2})=f(\vec{x_1})+f(\vec{x_2})$

Now I am able to show that a map is linear on basic maps, but I have run into a problem where I am unsure.

$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \sum\limits_{k=1}^n|x_k|$

What I have tried to this point:

I. $\varphi(\lambda* \vec{x}) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n|\lambda *x_k| \neq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \lambda|x_k| = \lambda*\varphi(\vec{x})$

II.

Now about the second one I am not sure anymore. The problem I see is that I can not apply the $\varphi(\vec{x_1}+\vec{x_2})=f(\vec{x_1})+f(\vec{x_2})$ since the sum has a $x_k$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi$ is not linear; consider the case where $\vec{x_1} = -\vec{x_2}$.